rintrojs problem returning to element once choices are updated
I have a shiny app that generates choices for selectizeInput() based on the value of another selector.  Specifically, it finds the unique values of the selected variable and then makes those choices.  I initialize the selector with selectizeInput() in the UI and then use observe({}) to identify changes in the inputs and then call updateSelectizeInput() to change the choices.  This all works fine.
The problem I am running in to is when I use rintrojs, the selector of choices is identified the first time through the app, but when the choices update, if I try to go back to those again, the element cannot be found.  Here's a few screenshots that identify the problem.  First, here's the screenshot of the first step of the tutoria:

Next, I can choose two values from the compare groups selector.

Next, it sends me back to choose a different value for Group 1, I choose "y".

Finally, when the tutorial tries to go back to the comparison groups, it just pushes the tooltip to the top left corner.

But, there hasn't been any problem updating the selector, you can see it now has the values D, E and F.

Do you have any idea why I cannot return to the compare groups selector once the choices have been updated.  As you can see from the code below, I use the same id to select the compare group selector, which works the first time, but not the second.  Here's the toy example.
library(shiny)
library(rintrojs)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("IntroJS Problem"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("browser", "browser"),
      introjsUI(),
      actionButton("btn","Interactive Tutorial"),
      selectizeInput("grp1", 
                     "Grouping Variable", 
                     choices = c("x", "y"), 
                     selected="x"),
      selectizeInput("compgroup", "Compare Groups (Choose 2)", choices="", multiple=TRUE, options=list(maxItems=2))
    ),
    
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  library(rintrojs)
  observeEvent(input$browser,{
    browser()
  })

  observe({
    g1 <- input$grp1
    if(g1 == "x"){
      chc <- c("A", "B", "C")
    }
    if(g1 == "y"){
      chc <- c("D", "E", "F")
    }
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "compgroup", choices = chc)
  })
  
  
  steps <- reactive({ 
    data.frame( 
      element = c("#grp1 + .selectize-control", 
                  "#compgroup + .selectize-control", 
                  "#grp1 + .selectize-control", 
                  "#compgroup + .selectize-control"),
      intro = c("Choose x for Group 1",
                "Choose two values for Comparing Groups", 
                "Choose y for Group 1", 
                "Choose two values for Comparing Groups"),
      position = "right")
  })
  observeEvent(input$btn, introjs(session, options = list(steps=steps())))
  
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


This is because introJs() stores the introItems once and if then the updateSelectizeInput runs during the intro, the stored target elements corresponding to that input are outdated (although they have the same id).
While one can solve this by reassigning the elements, e.g. for your above example by adding an onChange event in introjs():
events = list(
  onchange = I('
               if (this._currentStep % 2 == 1) {
                 this._introItems[this._currentStep].element = $("#compgroup + .selectize-control")[0];
               }   
               ')
)

, a better solution might be to use server-side processing, i.e., we use updateSelectizeInput with server = TRUE. It will work then, an example is below.
library(shiny)
library(rintrojs)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(# Application title
  titlePanel("IntroJS Problem"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("browser", "browser"),
      introjsUI(),
      actionButton("btn", "Interactive Tutorial"),
      selectizeInput(
        "grp1",
        "Grouping Variable",
        choices = c("x", "y"),
        selected = "x"
      ),
      selectizeInput(
        "compgroup",
        "Compare Groups (Choose 2)",
        choices = "",
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list(maxItems = 2)
      )
    ),
    
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel()
  ))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  library(rintrojs)
  observeEvent(input$browser, {
    browser()
  })
  
  updateSelectizeInput(session, "compgroup", choices = "", server = TRUE)
  
  chc <-
    debounce(reactive(if (input$grp1 == "x") {
      c("A", "B", "C")
    } else {
      c("D", "E", "F")
    }), 200)
  
  observe({
    req(input$grp1)
    updateSelectizeInput(session,
                         "compgroup",
                         choices = chc(),
                         server = TRUE)
  })
  
  
  steps <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      element = c(
        "#grp1 + .selectize-control",
        "#compgroup + .selectize-control",
        "#grp1 + .selectize-control",
        "#compgroup + .selectize-control"
      ),
      intro = c(
        "Choose x for Group 1",
        "Choose two values for Comparing Groups",
        "Choose y for Group 1",
        "Choose two values for Comparing Groups"
      ),
      position = "right"
    )
  })
  observeEvent(input$btn, introjs(session, options = list(steps = steps())))
  
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


